# Designing a new Live OS which for LaTeX ONLY

Tags: discussion

Do you think it sounds rational to design a Live LINUX OS which is totally dedicated to LaTeX and includes all packages?

All Linux distros do not support TexLive easy installation so users could go for this live version and do not have to go through the whole installation process, Besides they don't have to allocate a 2 GB space on their disk(if they want the full installation of packages).

Comment: As it stands, this is clearly not a meta-TeX-sx question (not about the site), but I'm reluctant to migrate to the main site as it's not really a question that's got a clear answer there either. Seems rather more like a discussion point, which the StackExchange model really doesn't work for.

Comment: it's about latex and its users generally, so I think it might find some answer... I know it does not fall in meta category but had no idea where else to ask the question and get TeX experts idea about such thing.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over using a portable installation of TeX Live? I can think of a number of disadvantages e.g. need to reboot, lack of access to other applications etc. But I'm struggling to see the advantages.

Comment: @cfr well the portable installation of TeXlive still needs installation and I heard some people had difficulty with installing it on Debian distro.besides many people are not willing to dedicate 3-4 GB of their diskspace to TeXlive so the can simply use this OS without any need of installation

Comment: Related Q on Main site: [Does Standalone LaTeX exist ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44137/15717)

Comment: @Negin: When I started with TeX in the late 1990s, it was about 1 GB of disk space, which was quite a lot at that time and even then I copied the whole packages and installed it (somehow manually). Nowadays, basically everybody has at least 500 GB disks in his/her computer, nobody should care about 3 oder 4 GB of disk space 'wasted' by TeXLive and I use other utilities such as shell-scripts, gnuplot, programming languages, I don't see any advantage of a standalone TeX OS.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : "Nowadays, basically everybody has at least 500 GB disks in his/her computer" ... or a SSD disk, in which case 3-4GB do make a difference. However, imo it doesn't really matter for this question: if you have the space (be it HDD or flash drive) for Linux+Texlive, you definitely have the space for Texlive alone.

Comment: @T.Verron: I had the SSD disk in mind too (as a contraction to my 500 GB statement), but I believe, it is not the majority of users having such an SSD, me included. But basically we agree. Disk space is so cheap nowadays...

Comment: The point about disk space is fair enough,Although I have never faced the difficulty of installation on my own distro,  the difficulty of installing the portable version on specific OSs such as Debian would worth of designing such OS. Actually the core idea of such os is the same as many other live OSs besides it skips the installation which might be hard for many users

Comment: @Negin: I never tried to use a portable version, so can not say anything about the install on a specific OS at all. The idea of a TeX OS is interesting, admitted. I still wonder about your restriction to 2GB (which is definitely not TeXLive - size), and I wonder, how you want to incorporate a) the TeX tree structure, b) updates of your TeX OS/distribution?